# testrpc Error: Module did not self-register

Tags: testrpc

I get this error when i run the `testrpc` command.

node version v5.11.1
npm version 3.8.6
web3 0.15.3
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely a node.js issue with your installation rather than a testrpc problem.  Try removing the node_modules directory and reinstalling:

```
rm -rf node_modules/
npm install
```

Comment: Thanks @dbryson Actually I had to uninstall both testrpc and npm.

Comment: Thanks @dbryson I actually had to remove npm, node and testrpc then go to https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions#option-2-change-npms-default-directory-to-another-directory to give npm write permissions, install node version 6 and then reinstall npm and ethereumjs-testrpc